# How to have multi output in Annotation NelmioApiDocBundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I would like to display return information from two entities in Api documentation:

- GeneralSpace
- User

I tried this:

```
    /**
     * Verifier le status de connexion de l'utilisateur et son token d'invitation (Page Orientation)
     * @View(serializerGroups={"list", "test"})
     * @api
     * @ApiDoc(
     * statusCodes={
     *      404="ORIENTATION.CODE_IS_INVALID",
     *      400="ORIENTATION_USER_HAS_ALREADY_JOINED_THIS_SPACE",
     *      200="ORIENTATION.USER_IS_NOT_LOGGED"
     *      },
     * output={
     *      "class"= "Freedom\DemophonieBundle\Entity\GeneralSpace", "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User",
     *      "groups"= {"list", "test"},
     *      "parsers" = {
     *              "Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Parser\JmsMetadataParser",
     *           }
     *      },
     * resource=true,
     * description="Verifier le status de connexion de l'utilisateur et sont token d'invitation (Page Orientation)",
     * requirements = {
     *      {
     *          "name" = "code",
     *          "dataType" = "string",
     *          "requirement" = "\w",
     *          "description" = "Code de l'invitation"
     *      }
     *  }
     * )
     * @param $code
     * @return \Freedom\DemophonieBundle\Entity\GeneralSpace
     */
    public function getVerificationAction($code)
    {
       ....
    }
```

I also searched in `NelmioApiDocBundle` source code. But it seems impossible to display information from multiple entity in documentation.

Do you have any idea about how we can do that? Can we set output manually? If it isn't possible, why?